# trying to add an event in calendarwidget for android studio using data I got from firestore and display them on a recyclerview

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, calendar

Currently I'm trying to develop a medication reminder for android and I am stuck and unable to display the specific event on a certain date. My code currently only works with displaying all of the information in the database but I want to put restrictions using date. I was wondering if that is possible and how would I go and tackle this problem because currently I am stuck.

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month += 1;
            date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            Log.d("Calendar", "Selected day change " + date);
            selectedDate = Integer.toString(dayOfMonth) + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            recyclerView1.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        }

  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyMedicationAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    medication_info medication_info = userArrayList.get(position);
    holder.InventoryMeds.setText(medication_info.InventoryMeds);
    holder.Medication.setText(medication_info.Medication);
    holder.StartDate.setText(medication_info.StartDate);
    holder.Time.setText(medication_info.Time);

    if (holder.StartDate.toString().equals(today.selectedDate))
    {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently I've tried using onSelecteddayChange and returns a string that has the same format the data in my database has. Then Im comparing the dates with string,equals and displaying the recyclerview adapter but its still showing the events for yesterday and future dates. I only want to display the events for today

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have added my solution currently its displaying nothing because of the visibility gone im assuming my conditions are incorrect.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There is no error it is not  just displaying the event i set on the specific day. Example I set a reminder for September 9 2021, so when i click on the calendar for September 9 2021 it should only display the reminders on September 9 but currently it still displays the remidners for September 8 and September 10.